# Store 2d array of objects as string

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, maze

I have a 2D array of objects of class Cell.  In a separate Maze class I read in the 2D array from a file, and now I need to have a method that returns the entire array as a String.  I'm not sure how to go about doing this, any help would be wonderful(I have a method in the Cell class that will return the cell as a string).

Comment: If you are trying to make a maze game, see this http://www.zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/sokoban/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print your matrix with 2 nested loops:

```
String temp = "";

// foreach row...
for( int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++ )
{

    // ... move across columns
    for( int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++ )
    {

        temp += (cells[i][j] + " ");

    }

    // let's move to a new line
    temp += "\n";

}

System.out.println(temp);
```

Granted that your `Cell` object has a `toString()` method.

Comment: I have confusion about inner for loop? any reason for i<cells[i].length? I doubt if this loops exits normally

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.deepToString()` method to print String of multidimensional array

```
    String[][] str = new String[][]{{"a","b"},{"c","d"}};
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(str));
```

Output

```
 [[a, b], [c, d]]
```

For this to work you need to have `toString()` method inside your cell class. Otherwise default `toString()` method will be used.